# Selections in D3: how to use parentNode.appendChild?

Tags: d3.js

I'd like to deal with overlapping SVG elements in D3.js using [this method from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120232/svg-elements-overlapping-issue).

However, due to the nature of my code, I want to use a D3 selector rather than `this` to re-add the element to the DOM. My question is: how can I use a D3 selector to get the relevant node?

This is how the original example does it:

```
this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
```

This is my attempt, which fails with "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined":

```
var thisNode = d3.select("#" + id);
thisNode.parentNode.appendChild(thisNode);
```

This JSFiddle (adapted from [the original example](http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/1197731)) demonstrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/cpcj5/

How is my D3 selection different from the `this` in the original example? I tried using `thisNode.node().parentNode.appendChild(thisNode)` but that also failed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`.parentNode` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Node.parentNode) is for a DOM element, not a [d3 selection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections).

To access the DOM element from a d3 selection is a little tricky, and there are often better ways to achieve what you want to do. Regardless, if you have a single element selected, it will be the first and only item within the first item of a d3.selection - i.e. you need to access it like so:

```
var someIdDOMelement = d3.select("#someid")[0][0];
```

An edited example of your original using this: http://jsfiddle.net/cpcj5/1/

If you have the id and specifically want to get the DOM element, I'd just go with [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById):

```
var someIdDOMElement = document.getElementById("someid")
```

Looking at [d3 documentation for binding events using on](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#animation--interaction), we can see that, within the function you bind, the `this` variable is the DOM element for the event which was triggered. So, when dealing with event handling in d3, you can just use `this` to get the DOM element from within a bound function.

But, looking at your code, I think it's easier to stick with the original implementation for re-appending the node using the original javascript methods, and then creating a d3 selection using `d3.select` on the dom element bound to `this`. This is how the original code does it: http://jsfiddle.net/cpcj5/3/

If you have any difficulties caused by this, please comment so I can address them.

Comment: Using `d3.select("#someid")[0][0]` works perfectly, thank you! As `d3.select("#someid").node()` would have if I'd remembered to use it as the argument. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use selection.node() in D3:

```
var thisNode = d3.select("#" + id);
thisNode.node().parentNode.appendChild(thisNode.node());
```